# Google Maps Api Promise TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'null')

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am having a hard time using the Google JavaScript Maps Api. I only have a html, css, and js file.

This is the error message I am getting when I inspect the page.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'null')
```

I have tried to solutions but it hasnt worked for me.

I added the `async defer` as part of the script tag and changed the initMap function to `window.initMap = function()`

Here is my Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>DREAM MIRROR</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <script src="traffic.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="traffic.css"> 



</style>
<a href="../index.html">Back</a>
<body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <div >

        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Origin">
           
        
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="to" placeholder="Destination">
            </div>
        </div>
        <b>Mode of Travel</b>
        <select id="mode">
            <option value="Driving">Driving</option>
            <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
            <option value="Biclying">Biclying</option>
            <option value="Transit">Transit</option>
        </select>
    
    </div> <!--Floating panel Div-->

    

    <div id="map"></div>
</div>


    

    <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
      async defer
    ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS file

```
window.initMap = function () {
     
    const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

    zoom: 14,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },

    });

    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    document.getElementById("mode").addEventListener("change", () => {

    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer)
});
}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer){
    let status;
    const selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").ariaValueMax;


    directionsService.route({
        origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
        destination: document.getElementById("from").value,


        travelMode: google.maps.travelMode[selectedMode],//ERROR HERE




    })

    .then((response) => {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Direction request failed due to " + status));
}
```

Traffic.CSS file

```
/* styles.css */


  
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url("tasks2.jpg");
    /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 120%;
  }

  #floating-panel {
        background: white;
        color: white;
        padding: 2em;
        border-radius: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 420px;
        margin: 1em;
        background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3))
      }
  
  
  .controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  
  #origin-input,
  #destination-input {
    border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.4em 1em;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background: #7c7c7c2b;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 105%;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  
  }
  
  #origin-input:focus,
  #destination-input:focus {
    border-color: salmon;
  }
  
  
  #mode-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: salmon;
    margin-left: 14px;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
  }
  
  #mode-selector label {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
      Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }


  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several typos:

1. `const selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").ariaValueMax;`
   should be: `const selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;`
2. `destination: document.getElementById("from").value,`
   should be: `destination: document.getElementById("to").value,`
3. Your `mode` `<select>`:

```
<select id="mode">
    <option value="Driving">Driving</option>
    <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
    <option value="Biclying">Biclying</option>
    <option value="Transit">Transit</option>
</select>
```

should be:

```
<select id="mode">
  <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
  <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
  <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
  <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
</select>
```

4. the closing `<div>` for the `floating-panel` should probably be before the `<map>` div (or you need more css to give the map div a size).

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**working code snippet:**

```js
window.initMap = function() {

  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },

  });

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
  document.getElementById("mode").addEventListener("change", () => {

    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer)
  });
}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  let status;
  const selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;


  directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
      destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode], //ERROR HERE
    })

    .then((response) => {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Direction request failed due to " + status));
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("tasks2.jpg");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 120%;
}

#floating-panel {
  background: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3))
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#origin-input,
#destination-input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.4em 1em;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background: #7c7c7c2b;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 105%;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}

#origin-input:focus,
#destination-input:focus {
  border-color: salmon;
}

#mode-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: salmon;
  margin-left: 14px;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#mode-selector label {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#map {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>DREAM MIRROR</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
</head>
<a href="../index.html">Back</a>

<body>
  <div id="floating-panel">
    <div>

      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Origin" value="new york, ny">


        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="to" placeholder="Destination" value="newark, nj">
        </div>
      </div>
      <b>Mode of Travel</b>
      <select id="mode">
        <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
        <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
        <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
        <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <!--Floating panel Div-->
  </div>


    <div id="map"></div>





  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</body>

</html>
```